# In phpStorm deployment preferences, is there a way to change the default excluded files/folders?

Tags: phpstorm

For example, I would like to always exclude .scss in the deployment options. This seems to be a per project setting. Is there a way to change the default files, so that I can always include or exclude certain types of files?

[image]

Comment: close all your projects (File -> CLose Project) until you get to the "Welcome to PhpStorm" window. Under "Quick Start" section: Configure > Settings. The changes you do here will be for all new projects (old projects will not be affected)

Answer (score 0):

Never mind. I found the answer by going to File -> Default Settings -> Deployment -> Options